# Ruby on Rails: Omniauth Session Create Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I'm getting two different errors:

```
"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100
```

and...

```
uninitialized constant SessionsController
```

...when trying to create a session after successful OAuth.

Here's my routes.rb

```
LiquidAdmin::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users

get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

resource :sessions, :only => :create
```

and my SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def create
@user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
self.current_user = @user
redirect_to '/'
end

protected

def auth_hash
request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
end
```

So it does the authentication... it tries to redirect the callback... and then it hits me with one of those two errors.

Basically I just want the user to be able to login with facebook and then be redirected to either the page he was on or the home page. (Preferably the page he was on.)

I have omniauth-facebook installed and working so the whole "auth" end of it is working... I just have to get my server end working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of silly actually... I named my controller SessionsController.rb Renaming it sessions_controller.rb fixed it.